# I gave input:type="text" in jsp for a field but it was not taking any inputs

Tags: jsp

it was displaying white space for text but it was not taking any input I don't know what is wrong

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstName">First
                        Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName"
                            class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="firstName" class="help-inline" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-lable">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
    <form>
    <input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName"
                                class="form-control input-sm" /> </form>
    <div class="has-error">
    <form><errors path="firstName" class="help-inline" /></form>
    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```